# Update and Import Dynamic Constants

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a file defining constants which have the current year as a part of them. In an effort to not update the code every year, I am making them dynamic. The constants can be updated by a dropdown list of years. When the user clicks on a new year, all constants should use that year.

How they are currently being used in a constants file being exported:

```js
export const someConstants = {
  CONSTANT_ONE_FOR_YEAR_2018: {
    url: CONSTANT_BASE_URL + "more-info-2018",
    otherInfo: {
      SUPER_CONSTANT_VALUE: "1"
    }
  }
}
```

then later imported via

```js
import { someConstants } from "../utils/constants";
console.log(someConstants.CONSTANT_ONE_FOR_YEAR_2018.url);
```

I was thinking there are a few ways, like changing someConstants to be a function accepting a date, but then that would require a date passed in every time.

```js
export const someConstants = (year) => {
  CONSTANT_ONE_FOR_YEAR_2018: {
    url: CONSTANT_BASE_URL + `more-info-${year}`,
    otherInfo: {
      SUPER_CONSTANT_VALUE: "1"
    }
  }
}
```

or using a class:

```
export default class constants {
  private _year: number = 2019;
  private CONSTANT_BASE_URL: string = "https://";
  set year(value: number) {
      this._year = value;
  }

  constantsWithYear = () => {
    return { 
      CONSTANT_ONE_FOR_YEAR_2018: {
      url: this.CONSTANT_BASE_URL + `more-info-${this._year}`,
      otherInfo: {
        SUPER_CONSTANT_VALUE: "1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But then to set and access it, you'd need to have the same instance of the class.

I realize technically constants shouldn't be dynamic, but how do I append a dynamic year to constants to be used throughout my project?

Answer (score 0):

Constants are read-only, therefore you can not modify them later on. 
you can use normal variable and make it like this:

```
`var someConstants = {
  CONSTANT_ONE_FOR_YEAR_2018: {
    url: CONSTANT_BASE_URL + "more-info-"+new Date().getFullYear(),
    otherInfo: {
      SUPER_CONSTANT_VALUE: "1"
    }
  }
}
`
```

Comment: The keyword const makes it so it can't be redefined, but you can in fact edit the object. Changing to var doesn't change anything.
`const foo = { a: 'b' };
foo.a = 'c';
console.log(foo.a); // c`

Comment: so you can use your second choice but with a few changes

Comment: export const someConstants = (new Date().getFullYear()) => {
  CONSTANT_ONE_FOR_YEAR_2018: {
    url: CONSTANT_BASE_URL + `more-info-${year}`,
    otherInfo: {
      SUPER_CONSTANT_VALUE: "1"
    }
  }
}